# NSDocument Versions has weird behavior

Tags: cocoa, save, nsdocument, versions, revert

Saving and Opening of file works perfect, but when selecting 'Revert To Save', on the right side of windows (previous documents) for a blink of second my document versions are seen then just blank copies.
And if I restore from this blah copy noting is changed but if I save and reopen the document   it is restored to the previous version. I am not sure how it is happening.
I have checked the official Apple document and WWDC videos but I am not near to solving this.
Please help?

In my NSDocument subclass, I have implemented this methods:

```
+ (BOOL)autosavesInPlace { return YES; }
+ (BOOL)preservesVersions { return YES; }
```

and reading from file is done:

```
- (BOOL)readFromURL:(NSURL *)absoluteURL ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError {

if ([typeName compare:@"public.plain-text"] == NSOrderedSame) {
    doucmentString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:absoluteURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:outError];
return YES;
}
if ( outError != NULL ) {
    *outError = [NSError errorWithDomain:NSOSStatusErrorDomain code:unimpErr userInfo:NULL];
}
return NO;
}
```

And in Windows Controller did load I am setting the string to MyDocument which is IBOutlet to NSTextview:

```
- (void)windowControllerDidLoadNib:(NSWindowController *)aController
{
[super windowControllerDidLoadNib:aController];
[myDocument insertText:doucmentString];
[self updateChangeCount:NSChangeAutosaved];
}
```

## UPDATE:

I have solved the version browser behavior by moving the `windowsControllerDidLoadNib` code to the `awakeFromNib`. So now I can see the document versions. Phew!

Still when hitting restore, my document doesn't get updated, only when closing and reopening they are show. There must be some updating code that i don't know about.
So still looking!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally everything is working in versions:
I am using this method:

```
- (BOOL)revertToContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)absoluteURL ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError {
    if(absoluteURL != NULL) {
    doucmentString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:absoluteURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:outError];
    return YES;
    } else if (outError) {
      //do nothing
    }
    return NO;
  }
```

and also changed my `awakeFromNib` method, instead of `insertText` I  now use `insertTextreplacementRange`

```
-(void) awakeFromNib
{
  if (documentString != NULL) {
  [myDocument insertText:doucmentString replacementRange:NSMakeRange(0, [[myDocument textStorage]length])];
  [self updateChangeCount:NSChangeAutosaved];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To update your document after restoring a version, one of the methods getting called is `- (BOOL)readFromData:(NSData *)data ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError`, which is also called when you open a new document. To know if this method is called when restoring a version I use to check if any IBOutlet is already set (i.e. myOutlet!=nil). There may be other manners to achieve this, so let me know if you find one :-)
You may also want to refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885639/restoring-from-versions-browser-on-osx-lion-not-working-ideas).

Comment: Nickkk, thanks. I did try the `- (BOOL)readFromData:(NSData *)data ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError` method, but still not solved. But from your link (thanks:), he used File Wrapper, may be Apple binds all this versions in a wrapper so only way to get them is to use that one. I will try this in few hours and will let you know.

Comment: and Nickkk, I can't vote you up yet, my reputation is not 15. Sorry!